# sort geonear search results in ruby on rails with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using below query to get search results

```
Org.where('content.attribs.name'=>'cuisine', 'content.attribs.value'=>cuisine ).geo_near([lon,lat], :max_distance => dist, :spherical => true, num: num_results)
```

now I want to sort these results by Ratings column in **desc** order

pls can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

The `geoNear` command returns a document, and not a cursor, so you can't call sort on that. You will have to do this in your application code.